# How to set default selected value for Rails SimpleForm select box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm trying to figure out how to set the selected option of a select box generated by [SimpleForm](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form). My code is along the lines of:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.association :store, default: 1 %>
```

Of course the `default: 1` part does not work.

TIA

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks that "default" *must* mean that we're talking about what you see when no value has been selected *and* still have it show the one that has been selected if one has?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Use the following:

```
selected: 1
```

Comment: <%= f.association :tipo, collection: Tipo.activos, label_method: :tipo, selected: 1, input_html: {class: "select2select"} %> complete sentence for me

Answer (score 9):

You can now use the following:

```
<%= f.association :store, selected: 1 %>
```