# Simple_form (rails) - How can I set default selected option if I have params[:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, selected

I'm trying to set value in my `simple_form` `association` field:

```
<%= f.association :names %>
```

Now in this field I have some values, for example: John, Jack, Jerry.

How can I set, for example, default value `Jerry` if I have `params[:name] = Jerry`?

I tried this:

```
<%= f.association :names, selected: params[:name] %>
<%= f.association :names, input_html: { value: params[:name] } %>
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use this code to set default value:

```
<%= f.association :names, default: params[:name] %>
```

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441061/how-to-set-default-value-for-rails-simpleform-select-box)